# ODE and semi flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am new to ODE and semi-flows. So, it is a beginner question.

If an ODE $x^{\prime} = h(x)$ admits a unique solution, is it right to say that the flow generated by this equation, i.e. $\Phi_t(x) = x + \int_0^t h(s) \,\mathrm{d}s$ satisfies those properties :

(a) $\Phi_0 = Id$;

(b) $\Phi_t$ is continuous $\forall t$;

(c) $\Phi_{t+s} = \Phi_t \circ \Phi_s$ $\forall s,t \geq 0$.

I can prove the first two points, but I fail to prove the third one. I try to prove this point in a particular case where $T$ is a contraction on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $h = T - I_d$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for a comment)

I guess you are stuck because of the notation (which may become quite confusing when dealing with flows). In fact, the flow $\Phi_t$ needs an initial state, because it acts by making the solution evolve by a duration $t$. In the formula you provided, the initial state is given implicitly by the initial condition $x = x(0)$. This formula can be extended to other initial states by "reconstructing" the flow $\Phi_t$ from the original differential equation. Indeed, the latter is integrated as
$$
x(t) - x(s) = \int_{x(s)}^{x(t)} \mathrm{d}x = \int_s^t \dot{x} \,\mathrm{d}\tau = \int_s^t h(x(\tau)) \,\mathrm{d}\tau,
$$
hence
$$
x(t_0+t) = \Phi_t(x(t_0)) := x(t_0) + \int_{t_0}^{t_0+t} h(x(\tau)) \,\mathrm{d}\tau.
$$
As is, you should be able to prove the third property more easily.

Comment: Thanks. I think. I managed to prove the third point, with your answer.